# Active state does not work with the query string in the url

Tags: navigation, query-string

I have couple of pages on the website `Home` and `Open Positions`. The problem is in the navigation menu, `active` class is not applied to the page if any query string is supplied to the page.

For instance, while visiting:

```
https://www.example.com/open-positions
```

This would have the 'active' class applied in the navigation menu, however,

```
https://www.example.com/open-positions/?t=technology&l=london
```

would not have `active` class applied.

Can anyone please tell why is that so and how can I solve this issue? In theory the page should be highlighted irrespective on query string.

Comment: Have you checked your console to see if it's causing some sort of javascript error? Or turned on WP debug?

Comment: This is now resolved. I had added the custom link in navigation for open positions. Hence it was not working. Changing custom link to a page link instantly solved the issue.